# Reading comma in content of csv file , matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a csv file that contains comma in contents.

% with dot

```
15.12.2012 11:27;   0.9884753
11.12.2012 11:12;   10.670.642
11.12.2012 10:57;   114.455.145

Gdata= textscan(fid, '%s %f')
```

It works well.

% but what to do with dot

```
15.12.2012 11:27;   0,9884753
11.12.2012 11:12;   10,670.642
11.12.2012 10:57;   114,455.145
```

How can I read it.

regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may solve possible unevennes  due to the presence of both ',' and '.'

```
fid = fopen('data.d','r');
Gdata= textscan(fid, '%s %s','delimiter', ';' )

% // cancels '.' and sets ',' as '.'
f = @(i) str2double(regexprep(regexprep(i,'\.',''),',','\.'));

Num = cellfun(f,Gdata(2),'UniformOutput' , false);

Num{:}

         ans =

       0.9885
       10.6706
       114.4551
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `textscan` doesn't respect locale settings, so there's no way to make it interpret the comma as a decimal point by modifying the current locale. As a workaround, you could read the entire line in, replace the comma with a dot and then use `textscan` to parse the line.

```
line = fgetl( fid );
line = strrep( line, ',', '.' );
Gdata = textscan( line, '%s %f' );
```

You may have to resort to `regexp` or something else fancier than a simple `strrep` if the line may contain commas that you don't want replaced.